# Attribute name "devsite" associated with an element type "html" must be followed by the ' = ' character

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried to rebuild the project, Create a new project & also reinstall the android studio but didn't solve the problem. Can anybody tell me how to get rid of it [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7A57c.png)

Comment: Can you show the code where is the error ?

Comment: I didn't write a single line of code i just pick a random name for the app..build it...and run the app..and therefore the problem pop up...it may have problem in gradle build...

Answer (score 0):

Message: Attribute name "android:color-" associated with an element type "stroke" must be followed by the ' = ' character.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).